# test method fails for execute function in scheduler batch class

Tags: apex, code-coverage, scheduled-apex, failing-tests, schedulebatch

I have the following Execute method and want to test it.The test method throws the exception of invalid email, not understanding how can I do it. Also, how can I test the opportunity Code?

```
//Batch Execute method calls findCostForWoD method
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scopeList) {

    List<Account> AccList = (List<Account>) scopeList;  
    if(!AccList.isEmpty())
    {                 
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();               
        for (Account prod : AccList)
        {               

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {prod.owner.email};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setSubject(prod.name );
            String bodyText='This is  Account which is going to expired :p and stageName value change from Job Created to First Email Sent. ';           
            mail.setPlainTextBody(bodyText);                                
            Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });


        }
    }     
    List<Opportunity> myOpps = [SELECT Id, Name, stageName  FROM opportunity where  AccountID = :AccList ] ;

    if(!myOpps.isEmpty()) {

        for (Opportunity prod : myOpps)
        {               
            prod.StageName = 'First Email Sent';                            
        }


        update myOpps;
    }


}
```

The test method for it is...

```
static testMethod void testMethod1() 
{
    List<Account> lstAccount= new List<Account>();
    for(Integer i=0 ;i <200;i++)
    {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name ='Name'+i;           
        lstAccount.add(acc);
    }
    insert lstAccount;        


    Test.startTest();

        ApexBatchFirstReminder  obj = new ApexBatchFirstReminder ();       

        Database.QueryLocator ql = obj.start(null);
        obj.execute(null,lstAccount);
        obj.Finish(null);

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Thanks so much for your positive reply. I'll keep things in mind. I've set the Email deliverability to All Email. Still, I am getting this error.

System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_EMAIL_ADDRESS, Email address is invalid: null: [toAddresses, null]

Comment: It would help if you were to [edit] your question to include the entire text of the error message **verbatim**. My only guess right now is that the org you're testing this in doesn't have email deliverability set to "all", causing an exception to be thrown which is ending your test. Other things that I'm seeing are: -Inserting 200 `Accounts` seems excessive for this test (Salesforce makes that recommendation to help ensure that code is properly bulkified) -Your test is missing the most important part of unit tests, _making assertions to validate results_

Comment: Beyond that, it's good to keep in mind that **you only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of a test**. If your test isn't failing due to an exception, the portion of the `execute` method that deals with `Opportunities` isn't covered because _you haven't created any `Opportunities` for your test_ (and thus your query returns no results, and your for loop and DML update aren't run).

Comment: Please also note: *Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is **the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as **[smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests**.* -
 [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you're running into here is one of what I like to call "related data".

In your `execute()` method, we see this line

```
String[] toAddresses = new String[] {prod.owner.email};
```

`prod` is your `Account` record, `owner` is a reference to a related `User` record, and `email` is data on that related record.

This is most often an issue people have with trigger context variables (trying to use "related data" without querying for it), but it can happen other places too (second most common would be when you pass collections of SObjects into a method).

Looking at your test method, we see

```
List<Account> lstAccount= new List<Account>();
for(Integer i=0 ;i <200;i++)
{
    Account acc = new Account();
    acc.Name ='Name'+i;           
    lstAccount.add(acc);
}

// some lines removed

obj.execute(null,lstAccount);
```

So you're passing `lstAccount` into your execute method, your loop doesn't explicitly set the `Owner` reference for the `Account`, and you don't re-query your `Accounts` before passing them to your method.

When your test starts executing the batch apex `execute()` method, `prod.owner.email` results in null, which explains the error you're getting.

Fixing that is pretty simple, you just need to re-query the `Accounts` you're passing to your `execute()` method before you call it.

```
static testMethod void testMethod1() 
{
    List<Account> lstAccount= new List<Account>();
    for(Integer i=0 ;i <200;i++)
    {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.Name ='Name'+i;           
        lstAccount.add(acc);
    }
    insert lstAccount;        

    // Re-query the accounts so that owner.email will be available when the
    //   code being tested is actually run
    lstAccount = [SELECT Id, Name, Owner.Email FROM Account WHERE Id IN :lstAccount];

    // If you really can't spare an extra query, we can work around that by
    //   manually setting the reference to Owner on the Account records.
    // OwnerId holds the Id of the related record, and Owner holds an independent
    //   instance of the related record (a User in this case).
    // Same thing applies to custom relationships (field__c is the Id, field__r
    //   holds an instance of the related record)
    /*
    // No need to query for the User record, just make one up
    User testUser = new User(Id = UserInfo.getUserId(), Email = 'test@localhost');

    for(Account acct :lstAccount){
        acct.Owner = testUser;
    }
    */
    Test.startTest();

        ApexBatchFirstReminder  obj = new ApexBatchFirstReminder ();       

        Database.QueryLocator ql = obj.start(null);
        obj.execute(null,lstAccount);
        obj.Finish(null);

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

That should help with your exception, though I'd recommend foregoing coverage for one line of code and prevent emails from actually being sent out as part of a test

```
//Batch Execute method calls findCostForWoD method
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scopeList) {

    List<Account> AccList = (List<Account>) scopeList;  
    if(!AccList.isEmpty())
    {                 
        List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();               
        for (Account prod : AccList)
        {               

            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[] {prod.owner.email};
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);
            mail.setSubject(prod.name );
            String bodyText='This is  Account which is going to expired :p and stageName value change from Job Created to First Email Sent. ';           
            mail.setPlainTextBody(bodyText);

            // Preventing emails from actually going out during a test
            if(!Test.isRunningTest()){
                Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
            }

        }
    }

    // other code omitted
```

Beyond that, I'll reiterate what has been said in the comments already.

The reason why you're not getting coverage for the part of your `execute()` method that deals with `Opportunity` records is that *you aren't creating any `Opportunity` records*. Thus, when you get to your query for `Opportunities`, it returns 0 rows. Salesforce doesn't enter for loops if there's nothing to loop over, and if your code isn't executed as part of a test, it isn't covered.

You *could* use seeAllData=true, but doing so is almost universally a bad idea (there are some situations where that's unvavoidable, but this is not one of them). Creating your own test data is really the way to go.

I see unit testing as having 3 phases:

1. Set up your test environment with all the data your code will need to run
2. Call the *one* method that you want to test (or DML, which usually ends up calling more than one method/trigger. The point is to focus on testing the smallest unit of code you can.)
3. Gather results, and use `system.assertEquals()`/`system.assertNotEquals()` to verify that your code actually did the things you think it should

It's hard to know if `Account` and `Opportunity` records will be *all* that you need for this test, but your test setup is incomplete if you don't create `Opportunity` records.

As for how to make the assertions for phase 3 of your test, that usually boils down to looking at your code or your business cases/specifications to see what you expect. In this case, you want the `Opportunity` stage name to be changed...so that's what you should assert.

```
// This code should appear after your execute() method (and after Test.stopTest()).
// You need to do another query to get the results of running your code because
//   the work that your code did was saved to the database (it is not available to you
//   in-memory here)
List<Opportunity> results = [SELECT Id, StageName FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :lstAccounts];

// This assertion isn't completely necessary, but your test would otherwise wrongly
//   pass if there weren't any opportunities
// assertEquals()/assertNotEquals() only requires 2 parameters, but the third one
//   (a message that gets printed when the assertion fails) helps to narrow down
//   the issue that you ran into.
System.assertEquals(false, results.isEmpty(), 'We expected to see some Opportunities after the execute() method finished running, but found no Opportunities');

for(Opportunity opp :results){
    System.assertEquals('First Email Sent', opp.StageName, 'Batch class didn\'t set the correct Opportunity stage');
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much @Derek F.  I wasn't having idea of crating the related records in Test Class, but now I have a clear understanding for the test methods, how to test them. Thanks so much, your solution worked like a charm!